# Why does my iMac go to sleep while I am using it?

Tags: imac, sleep-wake

My iMac (2014) running OS X 10.11.3 goes to sleep every now and then several times a day while I am using it.

I do not lose any work, but it is very annoying.  I do not have any hot-corners for sleep, or Energy Saver settings that cause the behavior.

After monitoring my machine using Terminal:

```
pmset -g pslo
2016-03-08 17:52:48 -0600 IORegisterForSystemPower: ...Sleeping...
```

When the event happens, I checked out the logs:

Console.app > System Log Queries > All Messages

> 3/8/16 5:52:48.206 PM CommCenter[299]: Telling CSI to go low power.

Why is CommCenter telling CSI to go to low power while I am actively using my iMac?

Comment: could it be some kind of infrared signal? did you try disabling the IR control?

Comment: No IR control on my iMac.

I checked with: https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18680?locale=en_US

Answer (score 2):

Well, that did not work.  Now I'm going to try this in Terminal.app for 5 hours of "don't go to sleep on me":

```
caffeinate -t 18000
```

Info on that command is:

```
man caffeinate
```

Comment: Can you please edit your own question outlining what you have tried, and only if it works, you can answer your question.

Comment: @IronCraftMan • Ultimately, I did not figure out how to fix the spontaneous sleep behavior.  I ended up buying a new machine, and reformatting the old machine.  Now the old machine, having been mowed over, reformatted, and the OS reinstalled fresh, it no longer has the sleep behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I did this to stop the CommCenter:

```
launchctl remove com.apple.CommCenter
```